# gradle NO-SOURCE message on linux

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I copied a gradle build project that builds fine on my local windows to my Linux build sever but it fails to see any source when run in Linux and prints `NO-SOURCE`, what am i missing here?

```
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test NO-SOURCE

:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your project structure? Make sure you are running build in the correct directory.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that Linux is case sensitive windows is not.